# Hybrid apps for iOS/Android/Windows 8

Tags: android, ios, windows-8, cross-platform

I hope this question is specific enough. I have a client for whom I made an iOS native app and an Android native app (same app, different platform). It's a fixed pixel design (I made this work for Android somehow:) and it works on iPad, iPhone and most Android devices (with some letterboxing). Now I am asked to write the same app for the Windows store and they want me to use HTML and JavaScript. My question is, when I use HTML and JavaScript, would it be "easy" for me to use this code into some sort of hybrid solution (PhoneGap, etc)? The app doesn't need much complicated functionality but does need to support push notifications on iOS and it needs to be able to play videos, preferably HLS. Any advice on what the best hybrid solution and do hybrid solutions allow you to build for Windows 8?

Comment: It's possible to write pugins for PhoneGap. Some existing: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a cross-platform developer working on PhoneGap and Titanium Appcelerator. The correct answer is "It depends". Currently the state of cross-platform development is not very recommendable. Yes, you can write plugins for PhoneGap and it does support windows phone but you will have a ridiculously hard time getting them to communicate with each other properly. I learnt this from experience.

If it was a hacking/hobby project to further the cause then I would say go for it but for a time-bound client project like yours, I would recommend against cross-platform solutions and go native instead. Plus native always gives considerably better control, speed and ease of development. You will probably develop it faster in native than cross platform anyway. I've played around with windows SDK and it seems easy to use and well-built with good documentation and you can use C# which is similar to Java since you have already used it on android.

You can also build windows 8 desktop apps using html and javascript natively but this isn't present in windows phone 8 yet.

As I mentioned, If you don't need too many native controls, then you can go cross-platform. For your requirements, it can be done. If you have already developed android and ios apps and only need windows app now, then going native would be easier. But if you have to make all 3 then you can go cross platform if your requirements are restricted to what you mention. Here's a good quora thread that discusses the pro's and cons:

http://www.quora.com/Is-Titanium-good-for-developing-iPhone-apps

Comment: the app that i'm making will not make use of any native controls. they custom design all the elements. why do you recommend against cross-platform solutions? what are the arguments? can you give examples of specific situation i might encounter that would take so much time to warrant developing three separate apps? the only things my app needs to do is: 1) load XML files from server and use this for navigation in the app 2) play a video 3) do some simple scaling animations 4) store some data persistently.

Comment: i ended up programming this in native c#/xaml for my client. thanks for your advice!

Comment: I bet you had an easier time than with cross-platform tools. Congrats!

Comment: yeah, although now i'm looking into developing a game for another client in cocos2d and i'm looking into Cocos2d-x. write once in C++ and then compile for iOS/Windows 8/Android... should be interesting :)

Comment: It would be great to get an update on this. "Currently the state of cross-platform development is not very recommendable" Is the situation you mention still valid today (almost 1 year after your original answer)?

Comment: @ChristopheHerreman Unfortunately Christophe, I still think so.

Comment: @AnupCowkur Is your judgment "Currently the state of cross-platform development is not very recommendable" still valid in 2015 ?

Comment: @Yahia I still think this is the case.

Comment: any update on your judgement about cross-platform for 2016?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look on [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com)

Main idea - they brings real native code for all platforms.
They have instruments to compile C# code that it can be used at all platforms
For example you should create UI in XCode (for iPhone) and use ModoDevelop to create DAL/BLL, then you can re-use C# code base over all other platforms

They have cross-platform iPhone/Android/WP7/W8 samples on [GitHub](https://github.com/xamarin)

Also see Q&A on Stackoverflow [tagged Xamaring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xamarin)

Answer (score 0):

We are starting to build multiple apps for multiple clients both in IOS and Android native platforms. The problem is we are going completely native which is taking too much time.

I would like to look at the linked in method (http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2012/10/a-behind-the-scenes-look-at-linkedins-mobile-engineering/) which is a more hybrid approach using HTML and native code.

The problem is I don't think Phonegap is that good - good for prototyping but maybe not for full versions of apps as it can be a bit slow and a bit buggy.

I would like to look into doing a model where we create like 65% HTML and 35% native to that device (like linked in)

Would anyone have any suggestions for this? Would people say we need a massive development team to pull such an approach off?

I welcome thought:)

Thanks